# How do you split source code in C into separate files?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read other peoples code but most code is broken up into separate files.  I haven't learned how to do that yet.  How do you split up code into separate files?  And how do you find the right source code file for a function?

Answer (score 3):

The key technique is using "header files", aka `.h` files, to expose the "should be visible from the outside" parts of each "source file", aka `.c` file. For finding sources across many files, see [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), unless the IDE you're using supplies even-better ways!

Answer (score 3):

Your functions can be declared (i.e., the function return type, name, and parameter types) in a ".h" file - also called a "header file".

Those functions are defined (i.e., the code that you write for the function) should be in a ".c" file.

That ".c" file should have an *include directive* at the top. It looks like this:

```
#include "myHeaderFile.h"
```

Now, to find the right source code for a function in Linux/Mac/Windows+cygwin, I would just use grep at the command prompt:

```
grep functionName *.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the #include preprocessor directive.  #include basically inserts of copy of the file you specify right at the line where you place it. This allows you to modularize your source code into multiple files, and yet have all of them compiled together.

see:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A quick note on ctags and cscope.

If your code is in a dir called src/ you can do this

```
#!/bin/sh
find src/ -name '*.c' >  cscope.files
find src/ -name '*.C' >> cscope.files
find src/ -name '*.h' >> cscope.files
find src/ -name '*.H' >> cscope.files
ctags -R -V --c-kinds=+p --fields=+S -L cscope.files 
cscope -b
```

Now you use ctags and vim and jump directly to a function called main with:

```
gvim -t main
```

There is some other good questions about that you can find in other question, 
so I will not go into more depth thatn this.

- [Vim and Ctags tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vimctags-tips-and-tricks)
- [What is a good tool to aid in browsing/following C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68247/what-is-a-good-tool-to-aid-in-browsing-following-c-code)

/Johan

Answer (score 0):

A single source file should contain a set of (preferably closely) related functions.  It should provide a coherent set of services to functions outside the source file.

A source file should have a header associated with it that declares the services provided by the source code.  (Exception: a single source file that contains `main()` and does not provide functions used by other files would not need a header file.)

Other files that use the functions include the header.  The file that defines the function also includes the header to ensure that the definitions match the declarations.

In general, it is a good idea for the source file to include the header first; this ensures that the header can be used 'standalone'.  That is, if some other source file needs to use the services of the header, it can include the header without having to worry about which other headers should have been included first.